# How can I identify numbers with space separator for thousands in a string with Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with text that uses spaces as thousands separators, e.g. 400 or 40 000 or 40 000 000 or 4 000 000 000. I need to identify the number in the string. Once identified, there are many options to re-format the number. I'm a rookie at regex. This doesn't work:

```
import re
line = '40) He had 120 hours to increase from 40 000 units to 20 000 000.'
regex = re.compile("(\d+ *\d+)")
re.findall(regex, line)
['40', '120', '40 000', '20 000', '000']
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following will do it:

```
regex = re.compile(r"(\d+(?:\s+\d+)*)")
```

This uses a non-capturing group `(?:)` that matches one or more spaces (`\s+`) followed by at least one digit (`\d+`). The entire non-capture group can appear zero or more times (`*`).

It is worth pointing out that it's generally a good idea to use raw strings (`r""` or `r''`) for Python regular expressions.

Finally, I'd probably tighten up the regex like so:

```
regex = re.compile(r"(\d+(?:\s+\d{3})*)")
```

This requires every group of digits except the first one to be exactly three digits long.

Comment: Thanks aix. To tighten it up even a little more, I updated it to limit the first group from 1-3 digits: re.compile("(\d{1,3}(?:\s*\d{3})*)")